# How to fix geofencing Trigger in Samsung Devices specially in latest one s9 and s10

Tags: android, android-geofence

Geofencing is worked well in other android devices like Nokia, Motorola, Lg. But not in give Exit and Enter Callback in the latest Samsung devices. It will Register and unregister well.

Answer (score 0):

S9 is Oreo and S10 is Pie. It requires notification running for background services and externally handle the permissions. Since oreo, you will not be able to keep bg services running continuously without notification. Use androidX library from Pie to lower support. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the issue reported at google issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135771329)

It  seems to be have been fixed now.